# SQL SUM values from column and dividide by number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to calculate a percentual...and I need to sum all values from a column (Its already ok) but I need divide the result by number of rows...

```
 select sum(voto) from tablename where id = numberHere
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `COUNT` to get the totalNumber of rows.

```
SELECT SUM(voto) / (COUNT(*) * 1.0) 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  id = numberHere
```

by adding `* 1.0` on the query will allow decimal places on the result.

or simply as

```
SELECT AVG(voto)
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  id = numberHere
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `avg(voto)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes `AVG(voto * 1.0)`

Comment: @JW. thx a lot..but the count need be the count of rows with the id that I have specified

Comment: @illDev yes, anyway if you want not to specify the `id` and you wan to calculate for the whole records for each id, just use group by `SELECT ID, AVG(voto)
FROM   tablename GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 3):

JW's answer is correct if you're looking specifically to do it by Summing/Dividing, but SQL has a function for that.

```
SELECT AVG(voto) FROM tablename WHERE id = numberHere
```

AFAIK, it automatically returns the same type as you input (except date columns, which should be parsed to seconds then re-encoded to date).

Answer (score 3):

AVG should work, count(*) should work, you can also use @@rownum to get the number of rows returned by the statement if you need to do more with that number.